# Which wire to cut from OBD2 connector to prevent theft of a Mini Cooper S?

Tags: obd-ii, theft-prevention

Just bought a Mini Cooper S convertible 2013 and read about the way thieves steal cars nowadays: by copying the key via the OBD2 connector.
There are several (expensive) solutions for this out there, like mechanical locks, keypads and magnetic swipe cards. But a simple hidden Switch that reconnects a cut wire when the car needs to go to the workshop would do the job as well.
Which wire should I cut and reconnect via a hidden switch to prevent thieves from starting the car or copying the key? I read somewhere the K-line but without any further explanation (and is that pin 7)? Thanks!

Comment: Cut any wire you like - if they turn up with a breakdown wagon ie flat-bed and load your car on it - no one will ask any questions.... Never had one question from others when we did exactly that... But we were legit...

Comment: I'd just wire a kill switch inline with the starter.